# tempdb data files don't shrink

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tempdb

Our `tempdb` used 99% of all available space on disk, but `DBCC SHRINKFILE` doesn't help.

This is how much disk space `tempdb` files take:

[image: tempdb files]

But when I check how much space is really used, I see this:

[image: space usage]

I tried to run

```
CHECKPOINT;
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE;
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL');
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('tempdev', 10240);
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('temp2', 10240);
```

But it had very little effect. Now I have around 9% free disk space.

How to release space used by `tempdb` without server or instance restart?

Comment: If you restart the sql server service, it will recreate tempdb to the original specified size. Not quite a server restart but …

Comment: Question is why did tempdb get so big ? Chances are it will grow again unless you fix whatever caused the growth in the first place ( or increase the drive size so having a big tempdb doesn’t bother you anymore )

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 I'd like to not restart the SQL Server service as well. Are you aware of some query that would show what caused the growth?

Comment: Try to shrink the files by small portions (10Gb maybe)